# Cut the materials of length N into specific lengths, Find minimun number of materials we need

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a list of lengths, we need to cut the raw material with length N to the length specified in the list. Please find the minimun number of material we require.

Example:

```
list = [6000, 3800, 1290, 1190, 341]
N = 6000
```

Output:

```
3
```

The first 6000 need a complete material, 3800 + 1290 + 341 = 5431, sharing a material, the remaining 1190 need a separate material.So we need 3 materials at least.

There's another way to describe the problem.

Constructing subarrays from elements in a giving array.The elements cannot be reused.The sum of subarrays cannot be greater than N.Find the minimum number of subarrays.

The subarrays which use the elements in the list above will be as follow.

```
[[6000], [3800,1290,341], [1190]]
```

Comment: I think it maybe a DP problem, but I don't know how to write the code.

Comment: What does "intercept the lengths" mean? Can you clarify with fully explained examples? I don't believe 'intercept the lengths' has a generally accepted meaning; if it is jargon in some field let us know.

Comment: Can you provide the expected output for your example?

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Do we need a total of 6000 + 3800 + 1290 + 1190 + 341 materials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is "[Bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem#First-Fit_(FF))" and this is an implementation of the First Fit (sorted) algorithm in JavaScript.

```js
    function firstFit(cutsUnsorted, materialLength) {
      const cuts = [...cutsUnsorted].sort((a, b) => b - a) // Sort decreasing for better result
      const cutsNumber = cuts.length
      const materialRemaining = new Array(cutsNumber).fill(0)
      const cutInMaterial = new Array(cutsNumber).fill(-1)
      let materialRequired = 0

      // Iterate through cuts
      for (let cutIndex = 0; cutIndex < cutsNumber; cutIndex++) {
        let materialIndex

        // Find the best material that can get cuts[cutIndex]
        for (materialIndex = 0; materialIndex < materialRequired; materialIndex++) {
          if (materialRemaining[materialIndex] >= cuts[cutIndex]) {
            materialRemaining[materialIndex] =
              materialRemaining[materialIndex] - cuts[cutIndex]
            cutInMaterial[cutIndex] = materialIndex
            break
          }
        }

        // If no material could get cuts[cutIndex], use a new material
        if (materialIndex === materialRequired) {
          materialRemaining[materialRequired] = materialLength - cuts[cutIndex]
          materialRequired++
          cutInMaterial[cutIndex] = materialIndex
        }
      }

      // Format and print cutInMaterial start
      let log = '['
      for (let i = 0; i < materialRequired; i++) {
        log = `${log}[`
        for (let j = 0; j < cutsNumber; j++) {
          if (cutInMaterial[j] === i) {
            log = `${log}${cuts[j]},`
          }
        }
        log = `${log.slice(0, -1)}],`
      }
      console.log(`${log.slice(0, -1)}]`)
      // Format and print cutInMaterial end

      return materialRequired
    }

    // ***** Start program
    const cuts = [6000, 3800, 1290, 1190, 341]
    const materialLength = 6000

    console.log(
      'Number of material required (firstFit algorithm):',
      firstFit(cuts, materialLength)
    )
```